# ReactJS positioning components

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, components, alignment

Sorry if this is a silly question, I am returning to code after a long hiatus and having to relearn a lot of the basics while trying to put together a portfolio etc.

In ReactJS is there a way to align components side by side horizontally without using material ui or bootstrap?

this is what im looking to create: -

```
  ----------------------------
  |                 |        |
  |   component 1   |  comp  |
  |-----------------|    3   |
  |                 |        |
  |  component 2    |        |
  ----------------------------
```

Component 3 drops to underneath the other two, how do I align the components, is it possible without a grid system?

edit: If it is better to use material ui, can you explain how I can position component 3 over 2 rows please

Answer (score 0):

The best way to approach this would be by using CSS Flexbox. For example, you could have the main container with the property `flex-direction: row;`, which inside would consist of two elements: a container with the property `flex-direction: column;` holding component 1,2 and another independent element, which would be component 3.

Comment: Thank you for your response arnelisk, I was able to do it with CSS flexbox using a nested grid, thank you for your help!